# Snap point to nearest line

Tags: algorithm, 2d, point, lines

I have a start and end point of every line. Every line can be only vertical or horizontal.

Example:

[image]

```
Lines = [
  ((1, 1), (1, 7)), // (start, end)
  ((1, 1), (7, 1)),
  ((4, 1), (4, 7))
]

Point = (6, 6)

NearestPointOnLine = (4, 6) // magic here
```

How do I calculate the closest point on the line for any point?

Comment: What should happen if the point is not level with a line? e.g. line `((1, 1), (1, 5))` point `(2, 6)`. Should that line be considered?

Comment: So, we are talking about segments, not lines.

Comment: wetson: Yes, it should.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating from segment to segment, for each segment, find the closest point from this segment to the point (a,b)

There are three cases:

- Horizontal line (x1, y) to (x2, y) and point (a,b) has x1 <= a <= x2, so closest point is (a,y)
- Vertical line (x, y1) to (x, y2) and point (a,b) has y1 <= b <= y2, so closest point is (x,b)
- None of these two above cases,in this case, the closest point is either the **start** or the **end** point of the segment. You can easily determine by calculate the distance from (a,b) to start and end.

After getting all the point, just return the point which has the shortest distance compared with others. Formula to calculate distance from point (a,b) to point(c,d):

```
int x = a - c;
int y = b - d;
double dist = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way. It does not care about the start and end of the lines but you can add that to suit. Should get you started.

Note (`line.x` and `line.y` are any point on the `line`, start or end)

```
var closestLine;
var closestDistance = maxvalue;
foreach line
{
   var distance = line.isHorizontal? line.x - point.x : line.y - point.y;
   distance = Math.Abs(distance);
   if (distance<closestDistance)
   {
      closestDistance = distance;
      closestLine = line;
   }
}
var snapX = closestLine.isHorizontal ? point.x : closestLine.x;
var snapY = closestLine.isHorizontal ? closestLine.y : point.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to consider several cases(I'll show how to do it for a vertical line, for a horizontal line it is almost the same):

1)Let's assume that ((x, y1); (x, y2)) is the line and (xp, yp) is the point.

2)If y1 <= yp <= y2, the answer is (x, yp). If yp < y1, it is (x, y1). Otherwise, the closest point is (x, y2).

To find the closest point for all the lines, you can apply this algorithm to all lines and choose the closest one.